# Is there a C++ library method that does what I wrote?

Tags: c++

I wrote some code that that essentially replicates the cast of a multi character literal to a long. I don't know what the name of this is called... but is there a library method that will do this?

```
std::uint64_t stringToLong(std::string str){
    std::int64_t val = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        std::uint64_t c = str[i];
        val = val | (c << ((str.length() - 1 - i) * 8));
    }
    return val;
}

int main() {
    
    std::cout << (std::uint64_t) '2254' << std::endl; //842151220
    std::cout << stringToLong("2254") << std::endl;   //842151220

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... perhaps? What is the goal exactly? I can't make it out by reading your description. Can you show what your expected output is and where your code fails?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What is `'2254'`? Pretty sure C++ uses double quotes for strings

Comment: It doesn't fail. The output is shown in the comments next to main.

Comment: '2254' is just a char casted to a long. It's just something random but it could be anything

Comment: It's a copy of `PHP\unpack('N',  '2254')` from PHP but it's not clear to me what it's doing in PHP either.

Comment: @smac89, C++ allows you to have multi-character character literals. They don't tend to be useful, but they exist, have type `int`, and IIRC, typically (in practice, not required) have the value of each byte of the sequence acting as a byte of the `int`.

Comment: There's `bit_cast` and its sibling `memcpy`, but endianness affects those of course.

Comment: @chris right, I'm pretty sure I need mine to be in big endian.

Comment: @chris do you mind explaining how endianness affects it? I know what endianness is... but how exactly does it "affect it?"

Comment: @LukeXu, Since the bytes in the resulting integral type could either be in order or reversed and the functions I mentioned copy the bit representation as-is, the endianness of the system determines whether the bytes in the string apply in order or in reverse. Granted it depends on what you use the result for. If you copy it somewhere else in order, then no problem I guess. If you pass it through a serialization library that sees your system is little endian and the result needs to be big endian, then an integral type with a big endian representation in it would be reversed after that.

Comment: It looks like your trying to hash the string? The function should take the string by const reference.

Comment: @chris thanks! You say my system is little endian... but isn't it big endian?

Comment: this is actually treats string as bigendian regardless what. but, apparently   `(std::uint64_t) '2254'` does have same result on littleendian system.

Comment: @LukeXu, It was an example, but every system I know of that someone would describe as "my system" these days is little.

Comment: @LukeXu depends what it is. Most are littleendian.Intel ISA-based PCs are littleendian, mobile ARM devices are too.. only one  bigendian I ever worked with was SPARC. VLIW can be both and some embedded are too

Comment: @chris You might say that of every personal computer (i.e. hardware system) but not of every program (i.e. software system).

Comment: @JaMiT endianness is feature of hardware. You probably think of byte order as feature of protocol.

Comment: @chris FWIW I quickly tried `memcpy(&result, "2254", 4);` and it's returning `875901490` instead of the `842151220`. Not sure why, but I'm going to dig into it.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out, it's because `875901490` backwards is `842151220`. Interesting...

Comment: [Fear the endian.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie OK, you want "endianness" for hardware and "byte order" for protocol (which I understand as meaning communication between software elements). What term would you use for processing *within* a software element?

Comment: @JaMiT  that's still protocol, I do not understand what you mean "element". Most architectures can work only with one byte order (ARM extensions  excluded). If you defined that something stored in other order, it's byte order, e.g. BO of unicode string :P

Comment: @LukeXu that's proof you're little endian.  `2254` is 0x32 0x32 0x35 0x34. your function treats it as littleendian `uint64` 0x34353232 by bitshiftting first characterter into MSB. Some librarires actually use something similar in prerpocessor to detect endianness of platform compiler is run of or detect it run-time.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It's a bit context-dependent, but you could read my use of "element" as "program" in most cases. I guess [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol) uses "entity" instead of "element"; maybe that's a better word choice. In any event, I understand that you prefer the term "byte order" when dealing with program internals. I disagree with excluding "endianness" (both terms seem fine to me), and I disagree with calling the internals of a program "protocol". However, that's going off on a tangent, so I won't continue that discussion here.